# How can I automatically delete older files based on their names?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm having an issue with a software generating many files.
I can't control the generation of files, but I can handle them after.
Files have this kind of name:

"RandomString".*ProjectNumber*.*Date*.*Time*.txt

For example:

```
1297729137.0004202.20180925.232147.txt
```

I want to keep for the same ProjectNumber, only the last generated TXT file.

Any idea how I can do that easily?

Comment: it will be easier if you just sort the files by date creation and leave the newest. Are also the files with the newer date generated generated sooner than the others?

Comment: Date and time are generation time, so the highest will be the newest.
There is a lot of files, however, not all the ProjectNumber get new files every time. So I can't sort by creation date, because maybe projectnumber XXXX last file was generated 10 days ago, and since then no new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Search files, keep the last one by project
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
   if "%%c%%d" gtr "!project[%%b]!" set "project[%%b]=%%c%%d"
)

rem Remove the rest of files
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
   if "%%c%%d" neq "!project[%%b]!" del "%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d.txt"
)
```

This method assume that just such a files exist in the folder; if not, just change the wild-card by `*.*.*.*.txt`

Comment: Fine solution! I didn't think it would be that easy in batch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should meet your needs:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem *.txt

$ProjectFiles = $Files | ForEach-Object {
    $FileName = $_.Name -Split '\.'
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name          = $_.Fullname
        RandomString  = $FileName[0]
        ProjectNumber = $FileName[1]
        DateTime      = [datetime]::parseexact($FileName[2] + $FileName[3], 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', $null)
    }
}

$FilesToRemove = ($ProjectFiles | Group-Object 'ProjectNumber') | ForEach-Object {
    ($_.Group | Sort-Object DateTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1).Name
} | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null }

$FilesToRemove | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

This retrieves all the text files and then creates a new custom PowerShell object with the name of the file and the properties you've specified from the filename by splitting on the '.'. We convert the date and time strings into a `datetime` object by using the `parseexact` method.

We can then use this new object to group the files by the project number, and then go through each of those groups sorting the results by Date, skipping the first result (which should be the newest dated project file) and returning the name of all others.

Then we can remove those file names with `Remove-Item`. When you're happy it's doing what you expect, remove the `-WhatIf`.

Note that this code assumes:

- Your directory only contains *.txt files with these files and no others
- The files always have the filename pattern you specified
- The datetime is always in the exact format you've specified, e.g two digit 24-hour etc.
- You're running this on PowerShell version 3 or newer.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job.
Had to adapt it cause the .txt was an example, in real I have 2 different extensions, so I just duplicated this.

Comment: FYI you can get files with two different extensions simply enough via: `Get-ChildItem *.ex1,*.ex2`, so no need to duplicate the whole code just for that.

Comment: Okay I will try this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to Mark Wragg, but using

- a `Where-Object` with a match and capture groups to separate the file name elements.
- a `Select-Object` to append calculated porperties PN and DT for ProjectName and DateTime
- grouping by ProjectName
- unrolling the group, sorting by DateTime descending and skipping the first (newest) to keep it
- removing the other with the `-WhatIf` option to just show what would be deleted.

---

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Where-Object Name -match '^(([^\.]+)\.){4}txt$' |
  Select-Object *,@{n='PN';e={$Matches[2]}},@{n='DT';e={$Matches[3]+$Matches[4]}} |
    Group-Object PN |
      ForEach-Object{ $_.Group | sort DT -desc | select -skip 1 | RM -Whatif }
```